# Correct RewriteRule On CMS php melody

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

every post on my website has 2 link

https://www.example.com/watch.php?vid=89e204ac2

and

https://www.example.com/example-name_89e204ac2.html

both links work .. but google index both links and this problem with duplicate content !
i want to force redirect first link to second link (Permalinks)

i found this in the .Htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}).html$ watch.php?vid=$2
```

Comment: Please correct the statement quote in 'site.com/watch.php?vid=89e204ac2 To  site.com/postname'. The post is difficult to read.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/watch.html/([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})$ watch.php?vid=$1   [L]

Comment: not working ...